# COM Object is empty.Why?

Tags: com

I am making com object in php. But when I write `die($object)`, it shows empty object. I have also registered my dll file. How to resolve this issue?

```
$obj = new com("dllfilename.classname") or die("Unable to include the dll");
die(json_encode($obj));
```

Comment: That is entirely normal.  COM uses a hyper-pure interface-based paradigm, the implementation of an object is completely hidden and only functions are exposed.  Basic reason why it is so easy to use such an object from any language.  No variables, they are hidden as well, accessing state is done through property getter and setter functions.  Neither json_encode() nor a php debugger knows enough about it to be smart about calling these getter functions.

Comment: I run my code but error occurs and that error is :                        com::com(): Type library constant  is already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sample BO API\Hello_worldCode.php on line 16                                 can u tell me the solution of this?